# My web hosting provider is providing 4 nameservers, which do I use to to point my domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, hosting, nameserver

I host my domain at GoDaddy, and purchased hosting from another website. The new website I'm using for hosting is providing 4 nameservers, while in GoDaddy it only provides 2 text fields to enter custom nameservers.

Example of the two text fields

[image: Example of the two text fields]

These are the 4 nameservers that my new hosting account is providing me

```
ns1.example.com
ns2.example.com
ns3.example.com
ns4.example.com
```

Which of the four nameservers do I use when pointing my GoDaddy domain to my new hosting account?

Comment: One, or the other, or both... It doesn't matter.

Comment: Surely it's possible to add more entries? This less cropped screenshot suggests there is a button for it: https://kinsta.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/change-godaddy-nameservers-5.png

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I've found when there's not a button some registrars will show a third field when you fill out the first two, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

All of them.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 5):

Best is to configure all of them if possible. But if not, you can select any two. All of them should serve exactly same information. You just have multiple servers for redundancy. Quite common strategy is to just take the first two.

Answer (score 1):

**Just use all of them.** It's like this just in case one of the nameservers are down. Or take two if you *really* want. `ns2` and `ns4` sound good!